# Flutter - Create Object data class | Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there anyone that could help me to create a data class for the response body below?

```
{
   "I am not a fixed value":{
      "malicious": true,
      "platforms":[
         "ANY_PLATFORM"
      ],
      "threats":[
         "MALWARE"
      ],
      "cache":"300s"
   }
}
```

As you can see, the element in the indentation is not fixed...
Generator gives me something like this:

```
class MyModel {
  bool? malicious;
  List<String>? platforms;
  List<String>? threats;
  String? cache;

  MyModel({
    this.malicious,
    this.platforms,
    this.threats,
    this.cache,
  });

  MyModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    malicious = json['malicious'];
    platforms = json['platforms'];
    threats = json['threats'];
    cache = json['cache'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['malicious'] = malicious;
    data['platforms'] = platforms;
    data['threats'] = threats;
    data['cache'] = cache;
    return data;
  }
}
```

But it is wrong... Any help is very welcome!
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your response contains every time one element

```json
{
   "dynamic_content":{
      "malicious": true,
      "platforms":[
         "ANY_PLATFORM"
      ],
      "threats":[
         "MALWARE"
      ],
      "cache":"300s"
   }
}
```

You can do that :

```dart
  Map<String,dynamic> data = {
    "I am not a fixed value":{
      "malicious": true,
      "platforms":[
        "ANY_PLATFORM"
      ],
      "threats":[
        "MALWARE"
      ],
      "cache":"300s"
    }
  };

  final key = data.keys.first;
  final myModel = MyModel.fromJson(map[key]);
```

if your response contains several items, you can create a List of `MyModel` with this code :

```dart
  Map<String,dynamic> data = {
    "first value":{
      ...
    },
    "other value":{
      ...
    }
  };

  List<MyModel> myModels = data
      .keys
      .map((String key) => MyModel.fromJson(map[key]))
      .toList();
```

Comment: It works. Thanks for your help. However, I will change the backend to not return dynamic content... it will be better to achieve what I want down the road.